# Load images in v-combox before mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm adding slot in v-combox
There're more than 100 Item, it loads the image while scrolling to comobox

```
<template  slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">   
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>
            <div class="title-content d-flex align-center">
                <img width="20px" :src="getImg(item.slug)" class="mr-2">
                <p>{{ item.coin }}</p>
            </div>
        </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</template>
```

I'm trying to load all images before mounted page and click to the combobox, so What should I do to prevent images loading while scrolling

Comment: What version of Vue and Vuetify?  It sounds like you want to delay displaying the entire page until the v-combobox has fully finished loading all it's images.   It's possible, but downside is you make the user sit there staring at a loading screen.  Use [v-overlay](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/#loader) (Vuetify 3 docs) with loading spinner if that is what you want.

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 2.6.0, Vue 2.6.14

Yes that's what I'm asking about, I tried to add an eager property in v-combobox like this, but it still loads only the first 20 items I guess on mounted and before opening the combo box 

I already added a loading screen until Requests finished
@yoduh